# c# сертификаты в токене (JaCarta, eToken, Rutoken)

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Вопрос такой: как выбрать и открыть в c# сертификаты, которые находятся в токене (JaCarta, eToken, Rutoken), в дальнейшем установить их в "Личное"?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вот так

```
static void InstallCertificate(string certifiacteFileName)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certifiacteFileName);
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        store.Add(certificate);
        store.Close();
    }
```

Чтобы Rutoken или eToken установились в личное, то нужно установить криптопровайдер(я использую КриптоПро CSP).